# Enable TLSv1 TLSv1.1 for specific Ingress with Nginx Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ingress, azure-kubernetes-service

I try to enable TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 for one specific ingress on a AKS cluster.

By default, only TLSv1.2 is enabled.

I don't want to apply this configuration on my all cluster, just on a specific webserver service.

Regarding the documentation, I need to add this annotation if I don't want to change nginx config by ConfigMap :

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-protocols: TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2`

but this has no effect.

Is it really possible to do this by annotation ?

Did I do something wrong ?

Thank you !

Comment: Which image/tag of the ingress controller are you using?

Comment: @EduardoBaitello I use this one : gcr.io/jenkinsxio/nginx-ingress-controller:0.30.0
Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 2):

The ConfigMap and Annotation configuration have different purposes.

As per [nginx-configuration/configmap/#ssl-protocols](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#ssl-protocols):

> Sets the SSL [protocols](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_protocols) to use. The default is: TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
>
> ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_protocols
> Context:  http, server

i.e., enable the specified protocols **to your Nginx Controller**.

`client --ssl-protocols-> controller --> backend`

---

On [nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-certificate-authentication](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-certificate-authentication), we can read:

> Enables the specified [protocols](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_protocols) for requests to a proxied HTTPS server.
>
> ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_protocols
> http, server, location

i.e., enables the specified protocols for requests **to a [proxied backend](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/) using HTTPS**.

`client --> controller --proxy-ssl-protocols-> backend`

---

As you can see, to set the protocols served by your Nginx controller, you only have `http, server` contexts available (i.e., you can't set this to specific ingress objects).